# Seeding fails with validation error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, seeding

To my User model I have added a new variable `new_email`. To this end I added:

```
VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-]+(\.[a-z\d\-]+)*\.[a-z]+\z/i
validates :new_email,     length: { maximum: 255 },
                          format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX }
```

In migration file:

```
t.string   :new_email
```

I have not added anything in my seeds file regarding this new variable. On seeding I get the error: `ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: New email is invalid`. If I remove the `validates` line from the model file it seeds succesfully. I have tried resetting my db: `rake db:drop`, `rake db:create`, `rake db:migrate` and `rake db:seed`, but with the same result. What could be causing this error?

The controller methods using params:

```
  def create
    @user = User.new(usernew_params)
    if @user.save                       
      @user.send_activation_email
      flash[:success] = "A confirmation email has been sent to you"
      redirect_to root_url
    else                            
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def update
    @user = User.friendly.find(params[:id])
    if @user.update_attributes(userupdate_params)
      flash[:success] = "Profile updated"
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

private
    def usernew_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:email,
                                   :username,
                                   :password, 
                                   :password_confirmation)
    end

    def userupdate_params
        params.require(:user).permit(:email,
                                     :email_new,
                                     :avatar,
                                     :organization, 
                                     :activated, 
                                     :password, 
                                     :password_confirmation)
    end
```

And my seeds file (left out other models without a relationship to this model):

```
99.times do |n|
  username  = "fakename#{n+1}"
  email = "example-#{n+1}@railstutorial.org"
  password = "password"
  organization = Faker::Company.name
  User.create!(username:               username,
               email:                  email,
               password:               password,
               password_confirmation:  password,
               activated:              true,
               activated_at:           Time.zone.now,
               organization:           organization)
end
```

Comment: Clarify this statement: "I have not added anything in my seeds file regarding this new variable" You mean to say that you have no User.create(new_email: 'foo@bar.com') or anything like that in seeds.rb? And in your users_controllers, under user_params, what do you have there?

Comment: Indeed, like you say, nothing in seeds regarding `new_email`. So the whole phrase "new_email" does not occur in seeds file. In the params in the controller I have included `new_email` to the params for the `update` method but not for the `create` method, since for the creation of a new record this variable will never be used.

Comment: Please post the controller rather than describing it. It's important to see exactly what's going on, as opposed to your assessment of what's going on. You can edit it to show just user_params and create methods as well as any code that might be setting up virtual attributes (look for stuff like attr_accessor).

Comment: I have added the controller methods to the original post. In my model file I have: `attr_accessor :remember_token, :activation_token, :reset_token`

Comment: Can you Add your seed.rb as well?

Comment: Added the relevant part of seeds as well.

Comment: Since you are validating new_email and do not specify that it can be nil or blank it fails validation. Try adding `allow_blank: true` to the validation and it should work fine. The controller has nothing to do with this question so you can remove this from the post.

Comment: Yes, that worked! Will you add this as the answer?

Comment: @engineersmnky Indeed, changing the validation would make the problem go away, but he's doing something interesting, with the two separate user_params methods. You see a literal problem "validation error," whereas I see a different problem lurking, which is "user_params x2." OP thinks new_email should not be passed at all and the validation should therefore never be called -- that's the *real* concern.

Comment: This might be over my head. But I was thinking: I use different params for new and update because at record creation only a few variables get set, while at update other variables can also be set. But when seeding and when seeds creates new records it does configure more variables than a user would normally do when creating a new record. Could this create problems?

Comment: > Could this create problems? Isn't it already? I've honestly never seen different sets of strong params used in the way you're doing. I could have given you the bandaid solution (to fix the validation) a long time ago, but there seems to be something else going on here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you are validating `new_email` on every request and not allowing it to be blank. Since it is not set in your seed file and you are validating based on a `Regexp` this will fail every time.

Based on your use case described I would recommend this

```
validates :new_email, length: { maximum: 255 },
                      format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },
                      allow_blank: true,
                      on: :update
```

This will do 2 things:

- It will allow `new_email` to be blank `""` or omitted completely `nil` without failing.
- Also since you are not even accepting `new_email` on create through the controller this validation will only run on `update`.

While validations that `allow_blank` are fairly lightweight I still try to advise against running code when it is not needed that is why I added the `on` parameter.

Comment: Hope I could ask a follow up question. Because of the line `on: :update` model tests fail. How would you deal with this? For example this simple one fails: `test "new_email should not be too long" do` `@user.new_email = "a" * 244 + "@example.com"` `assert_not @user.valid?` `end`

Comment: @Nick is the variable `@user` persisted at this point? e.g. `@user.save` has been called prior to setting this or `@user` was created with `@user = User.create` ? If it is not persisted then it is still a `new_record` and on update validations will not fire.

Comment: Yes, thanks, that solved it. In the model test in `def setup` I created `User.new` rather than loading a fixture and updating that in the tests.